# What's the extern for this function

Tags: extern, google-closure-compiler

I just don't get to understand the google closure compiler in advanced mode and the respective extern.

Concrete: can anybody tell me how to keep CC in advanced mode from renaming this function since I need to call it from my HTML (`<a href="javascript:searchAddress();">`)?

```
function searchAddress() {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var useraddress = $('#where').val();

    if (geocoder && useraddress) {   
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': useraddress, 'region': region}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                myPosition = results[0].geometry.location;
                myAccuracy = 150;
                echoAddress(results[0].formatted_address);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I thought I understood I need to write an extern file since the function is being called from external code, passing something like

```
window['searchAddress'] = searchAddress
```

or

```
function searchAddress() {}
```

but none of these and several other tries work. CC compiles without error, but the browser complains

> Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: searchAddress

searchAddress() has been deleted by CC and is not a function name in my min.js anymore. Thanks for any hint. Explanations appreciated, thanks.

Comment: There is no need for externs in this case. This should be sufficient:

    function searchAddress() {
      alert("me");
    }
    window['searchAddress'] = searchAddress;

It compiles to this for me:

    window.searchAddress=function(){alert("me")};

Comment: I think you're confusing externs with exports.  Externs prevent renaming.  Exports prevent dead-code removal.  The "window[...]=..." trick is the proper way to export a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create an extern, you want to export the function:

http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html

Add this to the code (not an extern file):

window['searchAddress'] = searchAddress

Comment: Thank, also to the guys for the comments above. I was indeed mixing up externs and exports and didn't get it that I just had to write my exports directly within my .js file... thanks